# Alternative for the spray-solution for installation of windows privacy film

Tags: windows

When trying to install privacy film on a window such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H5XTKG).  It seems like I need an installation kit. Most of the things seem simple enough to find alternatives for. However, the solution for spraying on the window before applying the film is more of a challenge. Should I use simple window washing spray? Just distilled water? Soap water?

**EDIT**

As pointed out by [Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248655/alternative-for-the-spray-solution-for-installation-of-windows-privacy-film#comment491112_248655) this film is adhesive film. Perhaps this matters.

The film came with no installation kit. It turns out that's sold separately. My question is how to create an alternative solution for spraying on the window before applying the film. This is needed per the instructions, in order to be able to smooth out bubbles. I don't want, however, to use something that will interfere with the film adhering to the window or somehow dissolve the film itself.

Comment: You linked to an **adhesive** film. That's entirely different from a **static cling** film (where you'd use water, per the directions, on the static cling film I used.) Adhesive films are a pain in the rear because the window typically has to be clean and dry and you only get one shot to put the stuff on straight. In any case, **follow the manufacturer's installation directions** since making it up as you go is likely to cause problems. The fact that a shopping site urged you to buy a kit with a spray bottle does not mean the film you linked actually needs a spray solution.

Comment: What do you want us to tell you beyond what's in the instructions for your product? Are you out of the supplied solution? Did you find a box of film without any solution? What's the real problem here?

Comment: I know the film I bought came with tools (squeegee, etc.)included. Not fancy ones, but adequate. As for wetting the window, instructions merely wanted it wet - "spray" was not requested nor required.

Comment: @Ecnerwal `Adhesive films are a pain...` - Now you tell me... :) . Anyway, the manufacturer's directions urge you to buy the installation kit which is sold separately and you're not aware of that until you get the film (unless you read all of the fine print on the product page) :(  . And I would like to avoid purchasing it, if possible, though it seems from your first comment that that might be an option.

Comment: @FreeMan It comes without the solution or anything else. Just the film.

Comment: Use distilled water with a drop of dish detergent or baby shampoo to break the surface tension and allow more uniform wetting/spreading.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. That seems logical. I'm a little worried about the shampoo interfering with the adhesive, however, I assume their solution has the same thing, if not, spreading the film would be too difficult.

Comment: If you don't buy the kit, you'll lose all warranty benefits. Follow the manufacturer's direction.

Comment: If the "proper" solution comes in small packages, you might consider buying one bottle of it, then looking at the MSD sheet to see what it's made of then look to see if you can purchase more of the main ingredient elsewhere at a lower cost.

Comment: @FreeMan Genius! Apparently [it's been done already](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/asin/B0006301W8/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_ql_hza?isAnswered=true).

Answer (score 3):

I have installed that exact same product on many windows in this house and my previous homes.  I always just used water with a little bit of dish soap in it.

The cleanliness of the glass before you install is a lot more important that which liquid you use to apply.  All it needs to do is keep the adhesive from sticking for long enough for you to position the film and press the bubbles out.